# Render Xamarin Forms view as Android view without specifying size

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a native Xamarin.Android `RecyclerView` [in my XAML](https://github.com/StephenClearyApps/PewBible/blob/76fb99128a5605a7c23af64452f5587661c0c1fd/PewBibleKjv/PewBibleKjv/MainPage.xaml#L12) as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/native-views/xaml/). `RecyclerView` manages one view per item on the screen (just displayed as a vertical list in my app). This works fine [if I use a Xamarin.Android view as the item view (in this example, a `TextView`)](https://github.com/StephenClearyApps/PewBible/blob/2a0e4cea99e2db897b96b73ddd8a248fb9193fa2/PewBibleKjv/PewBibleKjv/MainPage.xaml.cs#L60):

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
  var view = new TextView(parent.Context);
  return new TestViewHolder(view);
}
```

What I'd really like to do, though, is define a Xamarin.Forms control and have the `RecyclerView` use that. I can [use a built-in Android renderer to get an Android view](https://github.com/StephenClearyApps/PewBible/blob/76fb99128a5605a7c23af64452f5587661c0c1fd/PewBibleKjv/PewBibleKjv/MainPage.xaml.cs#L60), and that works (i.e., displays the correct data):

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    var label = new Label { Text = "Hello!" };
    var cv = new ContentView
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
        Content = label,
    };
    var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(cv, parent.Context);
    var view = renderer.View;
    renderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();
    view.LayoutParameters = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(parent.Width, parent.Height);
    cv.Layout(Rectangle.FromLTRB(0, 0, parent.Width, parent.Height));
    view.Layout(0, 0, (int)cv.Width, (int)cv.Height);

    return new TestViewHolder(label, view);
}
```

However, the resulting Android view always has its height and width set to whatever size I pass in, even if I use horizontal/vertical options of `Start` everywhere. What I want is for the Android view to only take up the space that it needs (at least vertically; it's free to expand horizontally).

Similar question, without any answers: [How to add Xamarin Forms content as a subview in Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198577/how-to-add-xamarin-forms-content-as-a-subview-in-xamarin-android-and-xamarin-ios)

Comment: Did you use StartAndExpand and remove the size value for example?

Comment: Hi，why not use Android native UI control, I think it is simpler than use `Label` and `ContentView` , because you don't need to consider the *Render*.

Comment: Is it of absolute necessity for this to be an embedded native control or would you also accept a custom renderer drawing a XF control the way you described it? Because i am pretty sure that this is very doable, but shared projects IDE support is awful in comparison (maybe my VS needs an update though...)

Comment: @Dbl: I believe it has to be a native view because of the way `RecyclerView` uses and recycles its views.

Comment: @StephenCleary Custom renderers use native views too, so the actual challenge of your request is having XF controls rendered from within a native android control then as it seems. I'll set something up then and get back to you later.

Comment: @Dbl: Yes. If I understand correctly, a renderer is exactly what I want - and there should be a built-in renderer that does exactly this. I just can't get the sizing to work right.

Comment: @StephenCleary i've gotten it to render the control now. Figuring out how to make it size to min height by itself now though. Guess it'll take a bit longer than i originally expected it to.

Comment: I was unable to find a working solution at this point and within bounty time span. I got it to render just fine, but unfortunately whenever i measured the forms control its height was 0 and it would not render unless i specify a height manually, which isn't what you want obviously. Would you like me to share the results anyway?

Comment: @Dbl: No; this is the same kind of problem that I had with the simple code in the question: the height is always 0 unless I specify it, which I can't do (in my case, items are of variable height).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the native UI control.

`TextView` instead of `Label`, `LinearLayout` or other `ViewGroup` instead of `ContentView`.

These Native UI control can achieve the same goal, just change `TestViewHolder` class and `OnCreateViewHolder` method, like below:

`TestViewHolder`:

```
public class TestViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    public TextView Label { get; }

    public TestViewHolder(TextView label, Android.Views.View view) : base(view)
    {
        Label = label;

    }
}
```

`OnCreateViewHolder`:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    TextView tv = new TextView(parent.Context);
    tv.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
    tv.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip,5.0f);
    tv.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(parent.Context);
    ll.LayoutParameters=new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    ll.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
    ll.AddView(tv);

    return new TestViewHolder(tv,ll);
}
```

Comment: As noted in my question, yes, I am aware that I can use Xamarin.Android views, and this is what I'm doing now in my project. The question is how do I use a Xamarin.Forms view.

Comment: @StephenCleary, have you taken a look at "[Xamarin.Forms Embedding](https://blog.xamarin.com/unleashed-embedding-xamarin-forms-in-xamarin-native/)" feature?

Comment: @Vahid: It looks like that would work for a page-level solution, but I would need something that can be managed by a `RecyclerView`.